# How to use recursion in the collection of a number to a second digit

Tags: c#

How to write a code that sum numbers from n to m using Recursion in C#

How can I change this code?

When you type a number for example 10, it combines 10 9 8 .... 1 I want to enter two numbers and then collect the numbers between the two numbers, for example 10 and 20 
 10 + 11 + 12 ........ + 20
=165

```
public class Recursion
{
    public static void SumFrom(int N, int M)
    {
        if (N == M)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(N);
            return N;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("+");
            return N + SumFrom(N + 1, M);
        }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the N:");
        int N = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the M:");
        int M = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        SumFrom(N + M));
    }
}
```

If the user enters two numbers
10 and 20
The program collects the numbers between them
Then the output appears

Comment: So what is your specific problem? What did you try, where are you stuck?

Comment: This sounds like homework to me :)

Comment: What is wrong with your example?

Comment: You have a few errors that the compiler will have picked up and you should fix but once you've done that your program should work. Are you having some trouble fixing the errors that your compiler has told you exist? As others have said you need to be more specific with what your problem is.

Answer (score -1):

Calling SumFrom Function incorrectly, it should be `SumFrom(N,M);` also you not print the value of int N and Total Sum.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the N:");
        int N = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the M:");
        int M = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        var result = Program.SumFrom(N,M);
        Console.Write("={0}", result);
    }
    public static int SumFrom(int N, int M) {
        if (N == M)
        {
            Console.Write(N);
            return N;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("{0}+", N); // this line prints current number on console.
            return N + SumFrom(N + 1, M); // code edited, you are not calling a method properly. 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [answer]. Explain what you changed, apart from swapping the code blocks, and why that would solve the OP's problem.

Comment: @CodeCaster: your question is How to write a code that sum numbers from n to m using Recursion in C#. I feel that your code seems good. if you want to print the numbers with as you said above and you can use my code. which will sum up the numbers from n to m and prints it on console.

Comment: It is not my question, I'm just a random visitor. My point is that your answer doesn't explain the OP what they did wrong, it says _"copy-paste this code, it will work"_. That is not the way answers are supposed to be written on Stack Overflow.

Comment: you need to be more specific with what your problem is, and what you want to achieve. I feel its better to read and understand [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: My problem is that you wrote an answer that's unfit for this site, and I'm encouraging you to read [answer], and to [edit] your answer to explain **what you changed in the code and why**. I'm not the question asker, and if you'd check my profile, you'd find out that I know pretty well how this site works.

Comment: you have compilation errors, seems like you are very beginner in programming. Please use suggestions given by your IDE for errors and warning. Please clear those to see output.

Comment: I edited my answer please check, I hope you can understand it.